# distinct and max query in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset like:

```
list1     list2   
a          e
a          e
b          w
a          e
a          r
b          c
```

I want to find most frequent item in list2 grouped by list1.

```
list1     list2    max
  a         e       3
  b         w       1
```

How can I get rid of the equal number of elements like b,w,1 and b,c,1 ?
I want to have one of them at random.

I tried something like this

```
qry1=spark.sql("SELECT list1 as clf1, list2, count(list2) AS value_count FROM table GROUP BY list2,clf1 order by value_count desc")
qry1.registerTempTable("try1")

qry2=spark.sql("select clf1 as clf2, first(value_count) as max_value from try1 group by clf2 ")
qry2.registerTempTable("try2") 

qry3=qry1.join(qry2, (try1["clf1"] == try2["clf2"]) & (try1["value_count"] == try2["max_value"]), 'inner')
```

Answer (score 0):

l  am not sure about the output you are looking for.still,you can try this query :

```
 qry1=spark.sql("SELECT * FROM (SELECT col1 as clf1, col2, count(col2) AS value_count FROM table1 GROUP BY col2,col1 order by value_count desc) a where value_count !=1")
```